# Pyqt5 - how to go back to hided Main Window from Secondary Window?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, qmainwindow, qapplication

If I click `Back` from the second window, the program will just exit. How do I go back to mainwindow in this case? I assume I will need some more code in that `clickMethodBack` function.

```
import os
import PyQt5
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QWidget, QLabel, QPushButton
import time
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize

class GUI_Window():
 
    def __init__(self):
        self.main_window()
        return

    def main_window(self):
        app = PyQt5.QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.MainWindow = MainWindow_()                                                  
        self.MainWindow.show()                                                                    
        app.exec_()                                                                      
        return
                  

class MainWindow_(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.TestAButton = QPushButton("TestA", self)
        self.TestAButton.clicked.connect(self.TestA_clickMethod)
        self.TestAButton.move(20, 0)

        self.CloseButton = QPushButton("Close", self)
        self.CloseButton.clicked.connect(self.Close_clickMethod)
        self.CloseButton.move(20, 40)

        self.TestingA = TestA_MainWindow()     
    def TestA_clickMethod(self):
        self.TestAButton.setEnabled(False)
        time.sleep(0.2)
        self.TestingA.show()
        self.hide()   

        try:
            if self.TestingA.back == True:
                self.show()
        except:
            None

    def Close_clickMethod(self):
        self.Test_Choice = 'Exit'
        self.close()


class TestA_MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(980,700))
        self.setWindowTitle("TestA")

        self.Back_Button = False

        self.closeButton = QPushButton("Close", self)
        self.closeButton.clicked.connect(self.clickMethodClose)

        self.returnButton = QPushButton("Back", self)
        self.returnButton.clicked.connect(self.clickMethodBack)
        self.returnButton.move(0,30)

    def clickMethodClose(self):
        self.Back_Button = False
        self.close()

    def clickMethodBack(self):
        self.returnButton.setEnabled(False)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        self.back = True
        self.close()






# Run if Script
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = GUI_Window()                                                   # Initialize GUI
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has two very important issues.

1. you're using a blocking function, `time.sleep`; Qt, as almost any UI toolkit, is *event driven*, which means that it has to be able to *constantly* receive and handle events (coming from the system or after user interaction): when something *blocks* the event queue, it completely freezes the whole program until that block releases control;
2. you're checking for the variable too soon: even assuming the `sleep` would work, you cannot know if the window is closed *after* that sleep timer has ended;

The solution is to use [signals and slots](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html). Since you need to know when the second window has been closed using the "back" button, create a custom signal for the second window that will be emitted whenever the function that is called by the button is closed.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        central = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(central)
        self.testButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Test A')
        self.closeButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Close')
        layout.addWidget(self.testButton)
        layout.addWidget(self.closeButton)
        self.setCentralWidget(central)

        self.testButton.clicked.connect(self.launchWindow)
        self.closeButton.clicked.connect(self.close)

    def launchWindow(self):
        self.test = TestA_MainWindow()
        self.test.backSignal.connect(self.show)
        self.hide()
        self.test.show()

class TestA_MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    backSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.closeButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Close')
        self.backButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Back')
        layout.addWidget(self.closeButton)
        layout.addWidget(self.backButton)

        self.closeButton.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.backButton.clicked.connect(self.goBack)

    def goBack(self):
        self.close()
        self.backSignal.emit()


def GUI_Window():
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    GUI_Window()
```

Notes:

- I removed the `GUI_Window` class and made a function, as using a class for that is not really useful;
- you should always prefer [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) instead of setting manual geometries;
- widgets should not be added to a QMainWindow as direct children, and a central widget should always be used (see the creation and use of `central` in the example); read more about it in the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#qt-main-window-framework);
- only classes and constants should be capitalized, while variables, attributes and functions should always have names starting with a lowercase letter;

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is straightforward and effective as always.